# node.js cluster module on multi-core or multiple node instances on single core

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

I am building a node.js backend running .12.7. This backend will be handling thousands of HTTP POSTS per second and each POST needs to be authenticated first.

The quickest way to implement the authentication of each POST is to generate a session key after authenticating the user against the first attempt and all subsequent attempts will be authenticated using this session key that is stored in an array in memory. The session key will expire after 10 minutes.

Since the array lookup is synchronous (taking 5 to 40 ms) I will need to increase the number of instances or workers that handle the connections.

The two options I am considering are :

1. Run multiple instances of node on a single core machine and set the load balancing to sticky so that every time that client sends a POST it goes to the same Server. This is to ensure that I am able to authenticate the client against the session key stored in memory.
2. Use the Cluster module to spin up workers on a multiple core machine. The advantage in this is that it may be easier to maintain as I wouldn't need to run several single instances.

When I look up Cluster on nodejs.org - it says "Stability: 2 - Unstable". I'm reading this as this is NOT production ready. But looking at blogs everyone seems to recommend using Cluster.

Has anyone implemented Cluster in production environment ? Are there any other alternatives I should look at ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: FWIW `cluster` is marked as [**Stable**](https://iojs.org/api/cluster.html) in the latest io.js (3.2.0 as of this writing) and thus it will be in node.js 4.0.

Comment: Thank you! mscdex. I visited the link you've shared, this looks good. I will start looking into this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using HMAC like Amazon does for S3 and what not.  This enables you to validate that a request is authorized but without having to keep sessions around for validation.

Basically, you take all of the request data and hash it along with a secret key that only the authorized party and the server know.  You then take this hash and send it with your request.  The server gets this data, re-hashes and if there is a match it allows the request.  For example, here's the original request:

```
POST /something
X-Key: thekey
```

Now we hash all this together with the secret and send it as another header:

```
X-Hash: sha1('POST /something' + 'X-Key: thekey' + secret);
```

The request can now be sent in the clear and the secret cannot be recovered since hash functions are one-way.  The server will receive that data and re-hash using the secret that it looks up for `thekey`.  If the calculated hash matches the value of `X-Hash`, then it knows that only someone with the authorized key and secret could have made (or signed) this request, and we should proceed.

There's one big flaw with this plan... it allows replay attacks.  There are two ways to solve that.  The easiest and generally effective-enough method is to add an expiration date to the request.

```
POST /something?expires=2015-09-01T11:45:00Z
```

Since each signed request will have their own hash, someone can't simply change the expiration date without invalidating the request.  The request can then only be replayed up until the point of expiration.

A more solid way to prevent replay attacks, but more difficult to implement, is to use a nonce.  Basically, you add a bit of data to the request that you then store in your data set and promise to never use again.  Ideally, it's a random nonce.

```
POST /something?nonce=oijwioj3wdlkjfoj234234ojwefoij
```

If someone tries to replay this request, your server sees that this nonce was already used by checking the nonce database, and then rejects the request.

That's HMAC.  Now, you're probably noticing that this doesn't directly solve your problem because at a minimum, you need a way to look up a key/secret.  This is where you can get creative.

You can generate keys programmatically based on another key.  Maybe the server initially handing out this session key has some sort of master key for which it derives other keys and secrets.  Maybe by hashing the key specified by the client in `X-Key` with our master key, we get `secret`.  This means that you would have to change the master key (and therefore all keys/secrets) if you ever needed to revoke, but that might be acceptable in your situation.  Maybe we rotate keys every request and have an expiration date.  There are a lot of ways to handle this situation but it depends on your specific request.

The point is to build a system that requires no lookups at all to verify that the request is authorized.  This is possible if the request includes enough information.  All you need really is a signature on the request that could only be calculated by an authorized party.  I think you'll find that this applies to your problem quite well.

Comment: Brad -- Thank you!!

I like your approach of using a hash. This will be a much more elegant solution and will allow a more equal balancing of my connections across my node instances.
I accept your answer. I tried to upvote but since I'm a newbie I do not have enough points to vote on your solution.

Comment: Thanks Brad. This one says it is still experimental.

My Server will be node.js and my clients are going to be ios and android devices. Are you aware of any hmac generator libraries that I can use in both - client and server ?

Comment: @Pankaj I've found that everyone does HMAC slightly differently.  I don't know of any for those platforms but I'm sure it's out there.  The main differences are in generating the digest (specifically... what to use in the digest) and where to put the hash (in a header or in the query string itself).

Comment: Thanks Brad. I'll spend some time with this now.

I appreciate your help on this.